# is it bad practice to throw a custom exception that will not be caught by the try block?

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, jpa

I have the following code, the RepositoryException will be handled by a global ExceptionHandler.

```
public Category update(Category entity) {
        
        try {
            em = emf.createEntityManager();
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            Category category = em.find(Category.class, entity.getId());
                        if(category == null)
                              //is this okay?
                              throw new RepositoryException("category not found");
            category.setName(entity.getName());
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            return entity;
        } catch (PersistenceException e) {
            em.getTransaction().rollback();
            if (e.getCause().getCause() instanceof ConstraintViolationException
                    && ((ConstraintViolationException) e.getCause().getCause()).getSQLException().getMessage()
                            .contains("UC_categories_name"))
                throw new RepositoryException("category already exists");
            throw e;
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }
```

If you know another way to update entities while minimizing the number of database queries, you can comment it.

Comment: Throwing an exception from a method is not inherently bad.  Exceptions are a reasonable and common way to terminate a method and return control to the calling code.  Checked exceptions exist to explicitly indicate that a method *can* throw a particular exception.  What that calling code does with that exception is up to that calling code.

Comment: It depends on whether the exception is something a caller can reasonably expect to happen.  In your case, I think you’re doing the right thing.  The caller should not be trying to update a nonexistent Category;  instead of catching that exception, the caller should be making sure they don’t try to update an invalid Category in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, choosing to throw a custom exception like RepositoryException when the category is not found is a reasonable approach, as it empowers the calling code to handle this situation appropriately. However, it's essential to ensure that the RepositoryException class is well-defined and provides sufficient information for the calling code to understand the underlying issue.

for exemple you can create an exception layer in which you have your custom exception, maybe also create an enum class to define all type of exception you use.

exemple : create a package that have an exception handler, exception response and error type (enum) for better structure.